# How Erlang access huge shared data structures like BTree in CouchDB

Tags: erlang, couchdb, actor

In CouchDB there's huge BTree data structure and multiple processes (one for each request).

Erlang processes can't share state - so it seems that there should be dedicated process responsible for accessing BTree and communicating with other processes via messages. But it would be inefficient - because there only one process who can access data.

So how such cases are handled in Erland, and how it's handled in this specific case with CouchDB?

Comment: You can look at their source code. If I were to develop a db using trees, I'd have different subtrees or even nodes of a tree to be managed by different processes.

Comment: I'd would look at sources if I could :). But sadly I don't know Erlang yet, I asked this question to better understood the approach and choose what to learn - Erlang or Clojure.

Comment: Thanks, managing different parts of tree by different processes makes since.

Answer (score 2):

Good question this. If you want an authoritative answer the 
best place to ask a question about couchdb internals is the [couchdb mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/couchdb-dev/) they are very quick and one of the core devs can probably give you a better answer. I will try to answer this as best as I can just keep in mind that I may be wrong :)

The first clue is provided by the couchdb config file. Start couchdb in the shell mode

`couchdb -i`

point your browser to

`http://localhost:5984/_utils/config.html`

You will find that under the `daemon` section there is a key value pair

`index_server   {couch_index_server, start_link, []}`

aha! so the index is served by a server. What kind of server? We will have to dive into the [code](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/1.6.x/src/couch_index/src/couch_index_server.erl#L14):-

It is a gen_server. All the operations to the couchdb view are handled by this gen_server. 
A gen_server is an erlang generic implementation of the client server model. It is concurrent by default. So your observation is correct. All the requests to the view are distinct process managed with the help of gen_server.

index_server defines three ets tables. You can verify this by typing

`ets:i()` in the erlang shell we started earlier and you should see:-

```
 couchdb_indexes_by_db couchdb_indexes_by_db bag     1      320      couch_index_server
 couchdb_indexes_by_pid couchdb_indexes_by_pid set   1      316      couch_index_server
 couchdb_indexes_by_sig couchdb_indexes_by_sig set   1      316      couch_index_server
```

When the index_server gets a `call` to `get_index` it adds a list of `Waiters` to the ets couchdb_indexes_by_sig. Or if a process requests it it simply sends a `reply` with the location of the index.

When the index_server gets a `call` to `async_open` it simply iterates over the list of `Waiters` and sends a `reply` to them with the location of the index

Similarly there are calls to `reset_indexes` and other ops on indexes which again send a reply with the location of the index.

When the index is created for the first time couchdb calls `async_open` to serve the index to all the waiting processes. Afterwards every process is given access to the index.

An important point to note here is that the index server does not do anything special except for making the index available to other processes(for example to couch_mr_view_util.erl). In that respect it acts as a gateway.Index write operations are handled by couch_index.erl, couch-index_updater.erl and couch_index_compactor.erl which (unsurprisingly) are all gen_servers!

When a view is being created for the first time only one process can access it. The query_server process(couchjs by default). After the view has been built it can be read and updated in a concurrent manner. The actual querying of views is handled by couch_mr_view which is exposed to us as the familliar http api.